# Login Controller using HashMapping Javafx

Tags: java, authentication, javafx, hashmap

Hey so im having a problem with my login controller (MVC pattern). Im trying to create a login screen that will remember user logins and all that jazz. But when i try logging in it always comes up as an error or unfound user. Im not sure why...

Right now the only user in the HashMap is ("admin", "pass")

Input in Login 
Username: Admin
Password: Pass

Output: User not Registered

or I get a NPE at the password check

```
public LoginController(LoginWindowGui view){
view.setLoginListner(new LoginListener(){

  @Override
  public void buttonClicked(LoginEvent le) {
    model = le.getPerson();
    model.setUserName(le.getPerson().getUserName());
    model.setPassword(le.getPerson().getPassword());
    System.out.println(le.getSource());     
    System.out.println(le.getPerson());

    if(RememberUserLogins.userMap.containsKey("admin")){
      String storedPassword = RememberUserLogins.userMap.get(model.getPassword());
       if(storedPassword.equals("pass")){
         System.out.println("Login Scussfull!!!");
       } else {
         System.out.println("Password Incorrect.");
       }
    } else {
      System.out.println("User not Registered, "
          + "Please Register now.");
    }

    System.out.println(RememberUserLogins.userMap);

  }      
});
```

Comment: Also tryed to surround with a try catch... didnt work (I know thats a sloppy thing to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up user with password when you call:

```
RememberUserLogins.userMap.get(model.getPassword());
```

You checked if the map contains key ("admin"), but then you call `get()` on the value not the key, which returns null, and causes the NPE

Comment: so there I need to call getUser() there?

Comment: So if i wanted to make it so that it just checks the entire hashmap for a new user id replace the "admin" and "pass" with the input from my text and password feild?